# Expected an Identifier xmemory vs 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I have an error in vs 2010 c++

```
IntelliSense: expected an identifier    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xmemory  228 28
```

When i try to compile a simple hello world program

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::cout << "hello World";
}
```

Edit here is the file that is having a problem

```
// xmemory internal header (from <memory>)
#pragma once
#ifndef _XMEMORY_
#define _XMEMORY_
#ifndef RC_INVOKED
#include <cstdlib>
#include <new>
#include <xutility>

 #pragma pack(push,_CRT_PACKING)
 #pragma warning(push,3)

 #define _ALLOCATOR allocator

 #pragma push_macro("new")
 #undef new

 #pragma warning(disable: 4100)

#ifndef _FARQ   /* specify standard memory model */
 #define _FARQ
 #define _PDFT  ptrdiff_t
 #define _SIZT  size_t
#endif /* _FARQ */

_STD_BEGIN
        // TEMPLATE FUNCTION _Allocate
template<class _Ty> inline
    _Ty _FARQ *_Allocate(_SIZT _Count, _Ty _FARQ *)
    {   // allocate storage for _Count elements of type _Ty
    void *_Ptr = 0;

    if (_Count <= 0)
        _Count = 0;
    else if (((_SIZT)(-1) / sizeof (_Ty) < _Count)
        || (_Ptr = ::operator new(_Count * sizeof (_Ty))) == 0)
        _THROW_NCEE(bad_alloc, 0);

    return ((_Ty _FARQ *)_Ptr);
    }

        // TEMPLATE FUNCTION _Construct
template<class _Ty1,
    class _Ty2> inline
    void _Construct(_Ty1 _FARQ *_Ptr, _Ty2&& _Val)
    {   // construct object at _Ptr with value _Val
    void _FARQ *_Vptr = _Ptr;
    ::new (_Vptr) _Ty1(_STD forward<_Ty2>(_Val));
    }

template<class _Ty1> inline
    void _Construct(_Ty1 _FARQ *_Ptr)
    {   // construct object at _Ptr with default value
    void _FARQ *_Vptr = _Ptr;

    ::new (_Vptr) _Ty1();
    }

        // TEMPLATE FUNCTION _Destroy
template<class _Ty> inline
    void _Destroy(_Ty _FARQ *_Ptr)
    {   // destroy object at _Ptr
    _Ptr->~_Ty();
    }

template<> inline
    void _Destroy(char _FARQ *)
    {   // destroy a char (do nothing)
    }

template<> inline
    void _Destroy(wchar_t _FARQ *)
    {   // destroy a wchar_t (do nothing)
    }

 #ifdef _NATIVE_WCHAR_T_DEFINED
template<> inline
    void _Destroy(unsigned short _FARQ *)
    {   // destroy a unsigned short (do nothing)
    }
 #endif /* _NATIVE_WCHAR_T_DEFINED */

        // TEMPLATE FUNCTION _Destroy_range
template<class _Alloc> inline
    void _Destroy_range(typename _Alloc::pointer _First,
        typename _Alloc::pointer _Last, _Alloc& _Al)
    {   // destroy [_First, _Last)
    _Destroy_range(_First, _Last, _Al, _Ptr_cat(_First, _Last));
    }

template<class _Alloc> inline
    void _Destroy_range(typename _Alloc::pointer _First,
        typename _Alloc::pointer _Last, _Alloc& _Al,
        _Nonscalar_ptr_iterator_tag)
    {   // destroy [_First, _Last), arbitrary type
    for (; _First != _Last; ++_First)
        _Dest_val(_Al, _First);
    }

template<class _Alloc> inline
    void _Destroy_range(typename _Alloc::pointer _First,
        typename _Alloc::pointer _Last, _Alloc& _Al,
        _Scalar_ptr_iterator_tag)
    {   // destroy [_First, _Last), scalar type (do nothing)
    }

        // TEMPLATE FUNCTION addressof
template<class _Ty> inline
    _Ty * addressof(_Ty& _Val)
    {   // return address of _Val
    return ((_Ty *) &(char&)_Val);
    }

        // TEMPLATE CLASS _Allocator_base
template<class _Ty>
    struct _Allocator_base
    {   // base class for generic allocators
    typedef _Ty value_type;
    };

        // TEMPLATE CLASS _Allocator_base<const _Ty>
template<class _Ty>
    struct _Allocator_base<const _Ty>
    {   // base class for generic allocators for const _Ty
    typedef _Ty value_type;
    };

        // TEMPLATE CLASS _ALLOCATOR
template<class _Ty>
    class _ALLOCATOR
        : public _Allocator_base<_Ty>
    {   // generic allocator for objects of class _Ty
public:
    typedef _Allocator_base<_Ty> _Mybase;
    typedef typename _Mybase::value_type value_type;

    typedef value_type _FARQ *pointer;
    typedef value_type _FARQ& reference;
    typedef const value_type _FARQ *const_pointer;
    typedef const value_type _FARQ& const_reference;

    typedef _SIZT size_type;
    typedef _PDFT difference_type;

    template<class _Other>
        struct rebind
        {   // convert this type to _ALLOCATOR<_Other>
        typedef _ALLOCATOR<_Other> other;
        };

    pointer address(reference _Val) const
        {   // return address of mutable _Val
        return ((pointer) &(char&)_Val);
        }

    const_pointer address(const_reference _Val) const
        {   // return address of nonmutable _Val
        return ((const_pointer) &(char&)_Val);
        }

    _ALLOCATOR() _THROW0()
        {   // construct default allocator (do nothing)
        }

    _ALLOCATOR(const _ALLOCATOR<_Ty>&) _THROW0()
        {   // construct by copying (do nothing)
        }

    template<class _Other>
        _ALLOCATOR(const _ALLOCATOR<_Other>&) _THROW0()
        {   // construct from a related allocator (do nothing)
        }

    template<class _Other>
        _ALLOCATOR<_Ty>& operator=(const _ALLOCATOR<_Other>&)
        {   // assign from a related allocator (do nothing)
        return (*this);
        }

    void deallocate(pointer _Ptr, size_type)
        {   // deallocate object at _Ptr, ignore size
        ::operator delete(_Ptr);
        }

    pointer allocate(size_type _Count)
        {   // allocate array of _Count elements
        return (_Allocate(_Count, (pointer)0));
        }

    pointer allocate(size_type _Count, const void _FARQ *)
        {   // allocate array of _Count elements, ignore hint
        return (allocate(_Count));
        }

    void construct(pointer _Ptr, const _Ty& _Val)
        {   // construct object at _Ptr with value _Val
        _Construct(_Ptr, _Val);
        }

    void construct(pointer _Ptr, _Ty&& _Val)
        {   // construct object at _Ptr with value _Val
        ::new ((void _FARQ *)_Ptr) _Ty(_STD forward<_Ty>(_Val));
        }

    template<class _Other>
        void construct(pointer _Ptr, _Other&& _Val)
        {   // construct object at _Ptr with value _Val
        ::new ((void _FARQ *)_Ptr) _Ty(_STD forward<_Other>(_Val));
        }

    void destroy(pointer _Ptr)
        {   // destroy object at _Ptr
        _Destroy(_Ptr);
        }

    _SIZT max_size() const _THROW0()
        {   // estimate maximum array size
        _SIZT _Count = (_SIZT)(-1) / sizeof (_Ty);
        return (0 < _Count ? _Count : 1);
        }
    };

        // CLASS _ALLOCATOR<void>
template<> class _ALLOCATOR<void>
    {   // generic _ALLOCATOR for type void
public:
    typedef void _Ty;
    typedef _Ty _FARQ *pointer;
    typedef const _Ty _FARQ *const_pointer;
    typedef _Ty value_type;

    template<class _Other>
        struct rebind
        {   // convert this type to an _ALLOCATOR<_Other>
        typedef _ALLOCATOR<_Other> other;
        };

    _ALLOCATOR() _THROW0()
        {   // construct default allocator (do nothing)
        }

    _ALLOCATOR(const _ALLOCATOR<_Ty>&) _THROW0()
        {   // construct by copying (do nothing)
        }

    template<class _Other>
        _ALLOCATOR(const _ALLOCATOR<_Other>&) _THROW0()
        {   // construct from related allocator (do nothing)
        }

    template<class _Other>
        _ALLOCATOR<_Ty>& operator=(const _ALLOCATOR<_Other>&)
        {   // assign from a related allocator (do nothing)
        return (*this);
        }
    };

template<class _Ty,
    class _Other> inline
    bool operator==(const allocator<_Ty>&,
        const allocator<_Other>&) _THROW0()
    {   // test for allocator equality
    return (true);
    }

template<class _Ty,
    class _Other> inline
    bool operator!=(const allocator<_Ty>& _Left,
        const allocator<_Other>& _Right) _THROW0()
    {   // test for allocator inequality
    return (!(_Left == _Right));
    }

        // TEMPLATE FUNCTIONS _Cons_val AND _Dest_val
template<class _Alloc,
    class _Ty1,
    class _Ty2>
    void _Cons_val(_Alloc& _Alval, _Ty1 *_Pdest, _Ty2&& _Src)
    {   // construct using allocator
    _Alval.construct(_Pdest, _STD forward<_Ty2>(_Src));
    }

template<class _Alloc,
    class _Ty1>
    void _Dest_val(_Alloc& _Alval, _Ty1 *_Pdest)
    {   // destroy using allocator
    _Alval.destroy(_Pdest);
    }
_STD_END

 #pragma pop_macro("new")

 #pragma warning(pop)
 #pragma pack(pop)

#endif /* RC_INVOKED */
#endif /* _XMEMORY_ */

/*
 * This file is derived from software bearing the following
 * restrictions:
 *
 * Copyright (c) 1994
 * Hewlett-Packard Company
 *
 * Permission to use, copy, modify, distribute and sell this
 * software and its documentation for any purpose is hereby
 * granted without fee, provided that the above copyright notice
 * appear in all copies and that both that copyright notice and
 * this permission notice appear in supporting documentation.
 * Hewlett-Packard Company makes no representations about the
 * suitability of this software for any purpose. It is provided
 * "as is" without express or implied warranty.
 */

/*
 * Copyright (c) 1992-2009 by P.J. Plauger.  ALL RIGHTS RESERVED.
 * Consult your license regarding permissions and restrictions.
V5.20:0009 */
```

but this is a file included in visual studio and i havent edited it so i can't see the problem

any help would be valued

Comment: i tried re-installing visual studio but i still get the error. any thoughts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed it was because i was trying to `#define pointer` and it was getting confused with the     `typedef const _Ty _FARQ *const_pointer;` line in the `xmemory` file